Removing a repeated sound from an audio file
I have a pre-recorded sound effect (FX) that will be played every 5 seconds. Together with that, I also play a music track for a few minutes. The result is recorded.
Now, I want to remove the sound FX from the recorded result.
My research shows that it would involve using a filter with the noise profile (obtained using FFT) of the sound FX.
My questions:

The FFT will give me the frequencies and their amplitudes over a given time span (say 2 seconds). How do I apply the filter? Should I apply the filter continuously?
Which filter should I use? A band-pass filter?
Should I check for the presence of the noise before applying the filter? If I know the exact timing of the sound FX, should I just apply filtering for that moment?

Thanks!
PS: I'm using AudioKit.

Is the sound effect added on top of other audio digitally with no processing afterwards? If so, you could just find the time reference (cross correlation) and subtract it.

No, the sound FX is played on iPhone, while the music is played somewhere else. Both are recorded by the iPhone. Playing and recording happen at the same time.

Ok. If the loudspeaker etc is reasonably linear and time invariant, then perhaps you can use an adaptive filter (an acoustic echo canceller)

Thanks, I'll take a look at the filter.
